# LISP - How to get the average length for nested lists?

Tags: list, nested, lisp, average, clisp

I have a problem. I need to get average length from this list: `(1 (2 3 4) 5 (6 7) 8 (9))`. It should be 2. And I have no idea where to start...

I tried to get `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)` from `(1 (2 3 4) 5 (6 7) 8 (9))` but I failed, because `(reduce #'append list-name)` isn't working.

I have idea how to calculate this but I need to get all lists inside (1 (2 3 4) 5 (6 7) 8 (9))
like this:

```
list1 = (1 5 8)
list2 = (2 3 4)
list3 = (6 7)
list4 = (9)
```

But I don't know how.

Can u give me some help?

Comment: why `(1 5 8)` at all? `1` is not a list, so it has no length. Similarly, `5` and `8`. You're left with `(2 3 4)`, `(6 7)` and `(9)`, with average list of exactly 2 indeed.

Comment: Thank you, so I need to get (2 3 4), (6 7) and (8) only. But how?

Comment: `(listp 1)` => `NIL`.

Comment: This gives me T or NIL if arg is list? I get this but still don't know how to get lists inside list.  (2 3 4), (6 7) and (8) from (1 (2 3 4) 5 (6 7) 8 (9))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun nested-lists-average-length (ls &aux (i 0) (n 0))
    (dolist (a ls (float (/ _______)))
      (if (_______ a) 
        (progn (_______ i) 
               (incf n (_______ a) )))))
```

[Fill](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm) ... [in](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_listp.htm) ... [the](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_incf_.htm) ... [blanks](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_length.htm). :)