# LISP - How to get average length from nested list? step by step explanation

Tags: list, nested, lisp, common-lisp, average

I know that this answer is answered but I'm new to LISP and I don't get it!

[LISP - How to get the average length for nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322716/lisp-how-to-get-average-length-from-nested-list)

```
(defun nested-lists-average-length (ls &aux (i 0) (n 0))
  (dolist (a ls (float (/ _______))) ;maybe (/ i n) ;;get average lenght of list
    (if (_______ a) ;??
      (progn (_______ i) ;??
             (incf n (_______ a) ))))) ;?
```

I wrote this function:

```
(defun average-sublist-length (list &aux (sum 0) (n 0))
  (dolist (x list (when (plusp n) (/ sum n))) 
    (when (plusp x)
      (incf sum (min x 100)) 
      (incf n)))) 

(average-sublist-length '(1 2 3 4 (5 6 7) 8 9))
```

If i want this to execute, I get error:

> PLUSP: (5 6) is not a real number Now I've got problems with calling it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're supposed to put some effort into finding a solution. If you have an actual programming problem, describe it here and tell us what you have tried and what the actual problem is. For learning basics of Lisp I would recommend this book: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/  You can download a no-cost PDF from there. Stackoverflow is not so much for other writing your code, but for developers with actual programming problems. There are better places to learn basics. Like: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnlisp/

Comment: you were supposed to take hints from the four links in that answer there. Each (except the first) actually points at the very function with which you had to "fill ... in ... the ... blanks" !

Comment: I made my function: (defun average-sublist-length (list &aux (sum 0) (n 0)) (dolist (x list (when (plusp n) (/ sum n))) (when (plusp x) (incf sum (min x 100)) (incf n)))) (average-sublist-length '(1 2 3 4 (5 6 7) 8 9)) If i want this to execute, I get error: PLUSP: (5 6) is not a real number
Now I've got problems with calling it.

Comment: Why `(min x 100)`?

Comment: What should `(plusp '(5 6))` have returned if not an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not think of what solving the problem involves?

To compute the average length of the sublists of a list, given the list, a running total, s, of the length of the sublists you have seen so far and the number of interesting elements, n, of the list you have seen so far:

- is it the empty list?

  - if it is then the answer is simply s/n.
  - if it isn't then is the first element interesting (a list)?

    - if it *is* interesting then the answer is the average sublist length of the rest of the list where s becomes s + the length of the first element and n becomes n + 1;
    - if it *isn't* then the answer is the average sublist length of the rest of the list s and n having the same values.

So, turn this into a function:

```
(defun average-sublist-length (l s n)
  (if <list is empty>
    (/ s n)
    (if <first element is interesting>
         <call average-sublist-length with
               the rest of l, s + length of 1st elt and n + 1>
         <call average-sublist-length with 
               the rest of l, s and n>)))
```

Now you need to work out what the calls should be like, what the initial call should be like and write a little wrapper function which calls this one the right way (or use `labels` and make this a local function).

Comment: I've figured something:
(defun average-sublist-length (list &aux (sum 0) (n 0))
  (dolist (x list (when (plusp n)
                     (/ sum n)))
    (when (plusp x)
      (incf sum (min x 100))
      (incf n))))
(average-sublist-length '(1 2 3 4 (5 6 7) 8 9))

If i want this to execute, I get error: PLUSP: (5 6) is not a real number

Answer (score 1):

Adding debugging information:

```
  ....
  (dolist (a ls ....)
    (print `(:debug :i ,i :n ,n :a ,a))
    (if ....) 
  ....
```

The example in [the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322716/lisp-how-to-get-average-length-from-nested-list) prints the following:

```
(nested-lists-average-length '(1 (2 3 4) 5 (6 7) 8 (9)))

(:DEBUG :I 0 :N 0 :A 1) 
(:DEBUG :I 0 :N 0 :A (2 3 4)) 
(:DEBUG :I 1 :N 3 :A 5) 
(:DEBUG :I 1 :N 3 :A (6 7)) 
(:DEBUG :I 2 :N 5 :A 8) 
(:DEBUG :I 2 :N 5 :A (9))
```